# Applying 0/1 to boolean logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset as below,
CURRENT YEAR  dataset:

| Year | ROA | Borrowings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1.2 | 23681 |

Previous YEAR  dataset:

| Year | ROA | Borrowings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 2.3 | 24682 |

So 2 dataset with different year.I dont want to combine dataset.

I am checking for boolean logic as below,

```
for key6, data6 in bank.items():   
 cy = data6[data6['index']=='2020']
py = data6[data6['index']=='2019']

ROA_FS = cy['ROA'].apply(lambda x:1 if x>0 else 0)
CFO_FS = cy['CashfromOperatingActivity'].apply(lambda x:1 if x>0 else 0)
C_ROA_FS = (cy['ROA']>py['ROA']).apply(lambda x:1 if x==True else 0)
```

First two lines in for loop works perfectly as its output is integer. but 3rd line I am comparing two different df's, after that  I converted to integer and float of the ROA columns as follows,

```
 (int(cy['ROA'])>int(py['ROA'])).apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='True' else 0)
```

When I applied it says following error,

```
'bool' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Please note that I am  comparing different ROA of different years

Expected output,
change_in_ROA = a['ROA']>b['ROA'], if true print 1 else 0. So output should be 0/1.

Thanks

Comment: `if x=='True'` is unlikely to work: `True` (no quotes, i.e., no string) may work, but more Pythonic would be `1 if x else 0`; or convert the boolean value directly to int (`int(x)`), or better yet, solve it in another, more practical, way.

Comment: Your error comes from the fact that you're trying to use `apply` on an integer, not on a DataFrame or Series. You should compare by column directly. And why convert to integer? Can't you compare by float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If same number of rows between both DataFrames use:

```
a['new'] = np.where(a['ROA'].astype(int) > b['ROA'].astype(int), 1, 0)
```

If not same rows is necessary first join DataFrames together, e.g. by column `col` (depends by data and what need) and then test:

```
df = a.merge(b, on='col')

df['new'] = np.where(df['ROA'].astype(int) > df['ROA'].astype(int), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks."Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" error occur. Note that I dont need to join dataframes, and also i have same number of rows. Please help on this

Comment: @Krish1992 - OK, so how need compare if one dataframe has e.g. 3 rows and second 5? Can you add logic here? Because in sample data in one row of data, so hard to know what need.

Comment: I only have 1 row with multiple columns in it with year row. So no additional row in it.

Comment: @Krish1992 - hmmm, without data which failed hard to know how help.  Please check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and add data which failed, also add expcted ouput from this data. It is new column? some list? Or something else?

Comment: I have edited the question.. I expect a 0/1 kind of thing as output. not list or new column. Here similarly I have several conditions to create 0/1 output.

Comment: @Krish1992 - Super, I add new rows to your question (is necessary different number of rows in each DataFrame because error `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`). So how looks expected ouput after this data?

Comment: @Krish1992 - Be free change them, but is necessary different number of rows between them.

Comment: No I dont have different number of rows. but if there is alternate way please let me know..

Comment: @Krish1992 So what is `print (len(a))` and `print (len(b))` ?

Comment: Both are 1. I have checked. The thing is I have created a new df with current year and previous year, so there is not possibility of additional rows, but in source df which you have changed have many no of rows, but here I am comparing current year ROA is greater than previous year ROA, if greater put 1 else 0.

Comment: @Krish1992 - So there is always `1` ? So why error `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` which means different lengths? or should be 1, but sometimes not?

Comment: Yes. there is no possibility of different lengths. but I dont know why this occurs.

Comment: @Krish1992 - I guess here is so loop, is possible see how use my solution?

Comment: I need a solution to check boolean i.e True put 1 else zero.  apart from numpy is there any other way?

Comment: Hard to know what need, because `Yes. there is no possibility of different lengths. ` So first try solve this problem and then my solution working perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230305/discussion-between-krish1992-and-jezrael).

Comment: it was because each dataset is having different index, how to ignore the index and compare values? dataset1 shows index value of 9 and dataset2 py shows index value of 10. thats why its not matching..

Comment: @Krish1992 - ya, then use `a = a.reset_index(drop=True)` and `b = b.reset_index(drop=True)`, but if different lenghs same problem I think `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: that index column made me to work for 5 hrs. thanks for giving me solution.

Comment: @Krish1992 - Thank you for patience, really. Happy coding!